# Migration of files from Win 10 to Ubuntu

Tags: files, windows-10, migration

I thought Ubuntu asked for files to import from the along-side operating system on installation. But it didn't, so how can I move them over to Ubuntu after installation?

The files I wanted to import are basically my browsers and bookmarks, along with passwords that are located in Win 10. Both operating systems are on the same computer.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what kinds of files you want to import to your new Ubuntu system. Also explain if your workflow involves any files or data going back to Windows from Ubuntu.

Comment: You can't import a browser; you would need to install a Linux version on your Ubuntu system.  However, you probably can export the bookmarks from a Windows browser and then import them into the Linux browser.  Which browser(s) are using bookmarks?  Where are the passwords stored on your Windows system?  If you are using a password manager that has a Linux version (e.g. KeePass), it may be possible to simply install the Linux version of the program and transfer the database file, or even point to the password file on the Windows partition.